# Can I swap with 1inch swap apis with forked hardhart?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, swap, web3js, hardhat

I have used hardhat to fork mainnet and imported the account in metamask. When I swap with that account on uniswap it works perfectly fine. But when I use 1inch swap api it connects with my mainnet and says i dont have sufficient fund for swapping. Can I use 1inch api and hardhat forked network to do the swapping in the same network?

[https://api.1inch.dev/swap/v6.0/1/swap?fromTokenAddress=${query.fromTokenAddress}&toTokenAddress=${query.toTokenAddress}&amount=${query.amount}&fromAddress=${query.fromAddress}&slippage=${query.slippage}](https://api.1inch.dev/swap/v6.0/1/swap?fromTokenAddress=$%7Bquery.fromTokenAddress%7D&toTokenAddress=$%7Bquery.toTokenAddress%7D&amount=$%7Bquery.amount%7D&fromAddress=$%7Bquery.fromAddress%7D&slippage=$%7Bquery.slippage%7D)

This is the api i m hitting from the front end.

Answer (score 1):

1inch API doesn't talk to local forks it's mainnet or public testnets only

Comment: What are the public testnets for 1inch?

Comment: 1inch protocol utilizes Ethereum's main testnets like Rinkeby, and Goerli for testing but for detailed and precise instructions check official 1inch documentation or their GitHub repository